# При добавлении второй галереи не работает код

Tags: jquery, изображения, gallery

Здравствуйте.
Нашел недавно простенький скрипт галереи:

```
$('.thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){

    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

И сама галерея:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div id="panel">
        <img id="largeImage" src="images/test2/image_01_large.jpg" />
        <div id="description">Игра Rage</div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbs">

        <img src="images/test2/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="Описание 1" />
        <img src="images/test2/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="Описание 2" />
        <img src="images/test2/image_03_thumb.jpg" alt="Описание 3" />
        <img src="images/test2/image_04_thumb.jpg" alt="Описание 4" />
        <img src="images/test2/image_05_thumb.jpg" alt="Описание 5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Смысл в том, что есть 2 типа картинок: маленькие для превью и большие для вывода. Все работает отлично.
Но мне понадобилось добавить еще одну такую галерею на странице. И код перестал работать.

Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать код!

Answer (score 2):

Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.
Поэтому вторая копия галлереи и не работает.

Используйте классы или другие id.